# admin on rest hide resource component in sidebar

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I need a resource with all its configuration, but I don't want it to be showed in sidebar
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the documentation, you can provide your `Menu` component to the `Admin` component using it's `menu` prop. See 
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#menu

Please note that this prop will be deprecated soon in favor of `appLayout` but you'll still use this custom menu in your custom layout anyway.

```
// in src/Menu.js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { MenuItemLink, getResources } from 'react-admin';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Responsive from '../layout/Responsive';

const Menu = ({ resources, onMenuClick, logout }) => (
    <div>
        {resources
            .filter(resource => resource.name !== 'excluded-resource')
            .map(resource => (
                <MenuItemLink to={`/${resource.name}`} primaryText={resource.name} onClick={onMenuClick} />
            ))
        }
        <Responsive
            small={logout}
            medium={null} // Pass null to render nothing on larger devices
        />
    </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    // Rerieve all known resources
    resources: getResources(state),
});

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Menu));
```

Comment: Side note about the `App` component `menu` prop: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/1881

Answer (score 8):

You can omit the list prop for a Resource if you want to hide it in the sidebar menu.

```
<Resource name="posts" />
```

Comment: solution was simple enough to work for my case. 
Indeed omitting the list prop workes, and you won't have to worry with creating a custom menu, until the day you'll have to cross that bridge.

Comment: If I am omitting the list prop then no URL is getting called and a blank page is coming

Comment: Could you please add the corresponding `import` in the answer? Is it `import { Resource } from 'react-admin'`?

Answer (score 4):

I found a different "hacky" way
You can add in your css the following to hide from the menu the resource

```css
.MuiDrawer-root a[href^='#/resource-to-exclude'] {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to hide the entire sidebar, and make it not visible to the user, in your `theme.js`

try add the following code:

```js
RaSidebar: {
  drawerPaper: {
    display: 'none',
  },
},
```

eg.

```js
const baseTheme = createTheme({
  overrides: {
    ...<components you want override etc>...,
    // React-admin
    RaSidebar: {
      drawerPaper: {
        display: 'none',
      },
    },
  },
});
```